# MJPG to V4L2Sink

Tags: gstreamer

I have a problem with linking the souphttpsrc, which received the mjpg stream, and a v4l2sink.

This works fine and play the source:
`gst-launch -v souphttpsrc location='http://ip:8081/?action=stream' ! multipartdemux ! jpegdec ! autovideosink`

If I try to link this to v4l2
`gst-launch -v souphttpsrc location='http://ip:8081/?action=stream' ! multipartdemux ! jpegdec ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video0`

But it doesn't work. (I'm currently not on the computer, so I paste the error later, but I remember that there was something like "Can't link the source to sink")

I think, that there is something like a convertation missing, that jpegdec can't connect to v4l2sink.

Have anybody an idea what is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a videoconvert or ffmpegcolorspace after the decode.  You may also need videoscale.